# Swift service class to retrieve Firebase data

Tags: swift, firebase, service

I have a service class to fetch data from my Firebase:

```
class Service {
    var myName = String?
    var myDev: String?

    func getData() {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.myName = name
            let dev = value?["dev"] as? String ?? ""
            self.myDev = dev
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

and realization in my Main class:

```
var service = Service()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    service.getData()
    configureLabel()
}

private func configureLabel(){
    self.titleLabel.text = service.myName
    self.devLabel.text = service.myDev
}
```

The problem is: data from Firebase fetched only after my label got values of myName and myDev.Thus, this values is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it does. The getData() method makes an asynchronous call to the Firebase service. Meaning, the **.observeSingleEvent** method of firebase runs in a async queue as most code blocks that makes a service call. So the compiler reaches to getData() line, pushes the block to a different queue and continues to compile the next lines which are in the original queue. If you want those lines to run after you receive the response, you may add a closure to your getData() method as a parameter.

You can do something like this:

```
    getData(completion: () -> Void) {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.myName = name
            let dev = value?["dev"] as? String ?? ""
            self.myDev = dev

            completion()
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        service.getData(completion: { Void in
            configureLabel()
        })

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

this is not the best solution, but it should solve your problem.

```
struct MyStructure {
        var name = ""
        var dev = ""

        init(with dictionary: [String: String]) {
            if let name = dictionary["name"]  {
                self.name = name
            }
            if let dev = dictionary["dev"]  {
                self.dev = dev
            }
        }
    }

    class Service {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        func getData(completion: @escaping ((_ structure: MyStructure) -> Void)) {
            databaseRef.child("Data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
                    completion(MyStructure(with: value))
                }
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    let service = Service()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        service.getData { myStructure in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.titleLabel.text = myStructure.name
                self.devLabel.text = myStructure.dev                    
            }
        }
    }
```